# Phonegap Plugin Issues

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm new to phonegap and plugins. I'm a little bit confused I download a plugin and I'm using angular to get a nice mvc structure and i one of my controller I'm using UniMag which is the plugin call to access the methods, but I get the console.log error that cannot find variable UniMag. what are some common issues related to that errors.

Thanks

Comment: Did you follow https://github.com/elizabethrego/cordova-plugin-unimag-swiper/blob/master/README.md?

Comment: Yes I did and cordova.plugins.unimag.swiper.activate(). It cannot find that method.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that many Phonegap plugins are not available in browser, you've to test it on a device or emulator only.

Comment: I tested using the phonegap emulator for ios

Answer (score 0):

When you use a cordova/ phonegap plugin you need to make sure the device is ready.
This is different from $(document).ready().

You need to wrap all your plugins like so;

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

  // vibrate device
  navigator.vibrate(1000);

}, false);
```

This will only work while on a device